# How can I compute the initial k-means centers with a robust seed selection algorithm in R?

Tags: r, algorithm, k-means, centroid

So far, I do a cluster analysis in R with the `kmeans()` algorithm (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.3/topics/kmeans). But with every run of the algorithm the result is slightly different.
Now I found this is because the initial centers of the kmeans algorithm are chosen randomly.
I also found that there is a possibility to compute the initial centers with a robust seed selection algorithm, also named Single Pass Seed selection algorithm or SPSS, described in this wonderful paper: https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1202/1202.1585.pdf

My question is as follows: **Is there a way of using this SPSS algorithm in R?**

For example by defining the centers of the `kmeans()` function?

I can’t find anything about it and I am happy about any help!

Comment: there is a distinct benefit of using a random seed ... just use it ... reverting back to same initial conditions is not helping you

Comment: it helps me because I want a reliable result, that doesn't change if I run the code more than once on the same data set.                                                      I work together with Non-Data Scientists and use the solution and in that case ONE reliable solution is so much better than n similar solutions.

Comment: If your problem is only repeatability, then choose k random points from your dataset and use them as initial centers. When you provide the random function with a seed, this will give you the same points each time you run your code on the same dataset.

Comment: Thank you Scott Stensland and SaiBot, but I am trying to find a way to compute usefull initial centers. And in the links you find in my question you can see that there are some mathematical ideas to find those useful initial centers and its even proven that the k-means result improve in their quality. So I search for a way to do the calculations of the links above or a similar calculation in R to find reproducable initial centers.